# How to append emoji keyboard library to custom keyboard app?

Tags: android, keyboard, emoji

I am making a keyboard app.I have managed everything successfully but i can not figuring out how to add emoji support to the keyboard.I have followed this  tutorial https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-integrate-emojis-keyboard-app/ and have integrated emoji library but it's need own EditText like below no 1 image.But i need emoji that will work for any EditText like below image no 2.How can i achieve that ?
image 1:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hani-momanii/SuperNova-Emoji/master/vid.gif
image 2:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Jm9.jpg

however i put this code to my OnKey method

```
    else if(primaryCode==55021)
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

it open a new activity but i want it to work like normal keyboard